# dejar marcado un jradioButton a la misma vez en dos jframe

Tags: java, java-swing

> Hola mi duda es como dejar marcado a la vez un radio button en 2
>   jframe en caso si se mueve uno se mueve el otro dinamicamente, muestro
>   imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> luego que marco ese radio button automáticamente me quede marcado el
>   radio button del otro jframe

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 private void rbt32ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {


}

private void rbt1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

       rbt32.isSelected();

    }
```

> Eso tengo como idea pero no queda marcado cuando lo marco en el primer
>   jframe tengo que volver a marcarlo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una variable static tipo boolean en el primer frame, le agregas un ActionPerformed a jradioButton para agregarle el estado a la variable que crearas, luego en el segundo frame en el constructor deberás buscar la variable static del primer frame y según su valor asignarle el estado a jradioButton del segundo frame.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Te invito a leer [answer]. Podrías enriquecer tu respuesta agregando algo de código relevante. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes compartir una Acción para los dos botones.

Por ejemplo:

```
 public class Accion32Horas extends javax.swing.AbrstractAction {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evento) {
         //aquí vamos a recibir notificación cuando se activo/desactivó
         //alguno de los dos botones de 32 horas
         JRadioButton boton32 = (JRadioButton)evento.getSource();
         if (boton32.isSelected()) {
            System.out.println("se seleccionó boton32");
         }
         else {
            System.out.println("se desseleccionó el boton32");
         }
     }
 }
```

Luego esta acción se la ponemos a los dos botones, porque comparten la misma acción y básicamente van a copiar comportamiento, porque ambas van a escuchar la misma acción. Cuando uno se seleccione/desseleccione el otro hará lo mismo.

```
javax.swing.Action accion32 = new Accion32Horas();

boton32Pagina1.setAction(accion32);
boton32Pagina2.setAction(accion32);
```

No lo he probado, pero debe funcionar.